# Google fit Api Response delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-fit

I'm trying to fetch  from Google Fit to integrate with my react native app, however both the steps and activities are not shown immediately and are only available after a huge delay (30 min to couple of hours). I checked their docs but couldn't find any information about this delay.

Any idea why there is a delay is getting updated response via REST API?

Im calling the google REST API, getting the response but not updated response.
When i tried nearly after 15-20 minutes i got updated response.